# Yearling Badge Bug?

Tags: support, badges, yearling-badge

I received my Yearling badge for Stack Overflow a couple of days ago, but according to the account page I have only been a member for 353 days (349 the day I earned it, I think).

How does Stack Exchange define a year?

Comment: Did you use SO with a cookie before registering for an account?

Comment: Now that I think about it, I originally registered with a different account and something funky happened which caused me to end up with two separate accounts. I contacted support upon noticing the problem (several months later) and they merged the two. Probably the source of the problem right there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [answer of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172468/when-is-it-acceptable-to-rewrite-someone-elses-code/1172554#1172554) was posted over a year ago (Jul 23 '09), so you've obviously been active that long. If Popular Demand is correct, this could be an answer your account inherited.