# Yearling badge too early

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, badges, yearling-badge

I like badges, but I don't think I should have been given a Yearling badge yet... [I've](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180215/bg100) only been on SO for 49 days!

I saw a comment on another [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58683/yearling-badge-bug) saying that a cookie may have been to blame. I may have visited SO over a year ago as a guest, but I certainly didn't create an account back then!

Comment: Ha, I just wrote a long comment, clicked on your link and saw that I was the person you're referring to. So... no further comment.

Comment: i dont think this is a big deal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your profile says you've been a member for 1 year and you have more than 200 points so you qualify.

It could be that when you visited Stack Overflow before you did create an account.

Comment: It seems I'm confusing "Member for" with "Visited". I must be blind!! I guess I must have created an account back then...